# How to redirect from tomcat to jboss

Tags: tomcat, redirect, jboss

I hired a web hosting with Tomcat and Jboss. Tomcat is running in the port 8080 and I need to redirect all the requests to the jboss server.  The administrator of the hosting server told me to use NGASI application adding the context /ElinkWeb that is the context of my jboss application but id does not work.

Any suggestion?, is it possible to include in the Tomcat's index.html a redirect instruction to jboos?

Comment: Google is your friend here: https://clients.javapipe.com/knowledgebase/62/How-to-redirect-your-Tomcat-or-JBoss-over-port-80.html

Comment: If you plan on redirecting all traffic, why do you use Tomcat at all? BTW, JBoss AS contains a Tomcat instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to serve some contexts from Tomcat instance and some other contexts from Jboss AS instance (or even handle some load distribution), you may take advantage of Apache httpd with mod_cluster as a smart load balancer [1](http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster)